# Calculated Field from Linked Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database, ms-access-2003

I'm using MS Access 2013.  My database has four relevant tables:

```
Table A) Numerical_Key_A, {Other Data Items}
Table B) Numerical_Key_B, "Adjustment Value", {Other Data Items}
Table C) Numerical_Key_C, {Other Data Items}
Table D) {Other Data Items}, Link-to-B, Link-to-A, Link-to-C
```

The way it works, however, is that the Link-to-C going into a record of Table D is always exactly "Adjustment Value" away from Numerical_Key_A.  As such, I would like to make the Link-to-C be automatically calculated when I enter Link-to-A and Link-to-B.

As far as I can tell, this would require Table D having a Calculated Field that gets its data from the linked Table B, which Access does not allow.  Is there another way to do this?  I'd prefer not to use VBA if possible, but if it's the only way, I'll just have to learn how to do it. (I know VBA for Excel, but have never used it in Access before).

Comment: I know how to create a query, but how would I use a query to populate the field?  Or am I misunderstanding how I should structure this?

Comment: Yes, you can create query which returns calculated data or even better, you can use query results to update table field. Which field do you want to calculate? Based on what condition?

Comment: In Table D, I want a field (which is linked to the primary key of table C) to be populated with a number equal to the current record's primary key of A, added to the related "Adjustment Value" from Table B.

So, I know how to create a generalized query of the whole database.  How do I make a query for just this record's values in related tables?

Comment: I'm doing some more research into SQL, since I only know very basic commands.  Some googling has led me down two roads that don't look like they'll work: SELECT INTO wouldn't work, because that creates a new table, and INSERT INTO wouldn't work, because that creates a new record.  I don't need a new record, I need an existing record's field updated.  What command will do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand yo well, all you need to do is to create join between tables, for example:

```
SELECT D.Field1, D.Field2, B.[Adjustment Value]
FROM Table_D AS D INNER JOIN Table_B AS B ON D.Link-To-B = B.Numerical_Key_B
```

For further information, please, see:
[Join tables and queries](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6)
[How to: Perform Joins Using Access SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

**[EDIT]**

*In table D, there is a field, which I have labeled in the above snippit as "Link-to-C". This field should be populated with the value of Link-to-A plus TableB.AdjustmentValue*

```
SELECT D.Field1, D.Link-To-C + D.Link-To-A + B.[Adjustment Value] AS CalculatedField
FROM (Table_D AS D INNER JOIN Table_B AS B ON D.Link-To-B = B.Numerical_Key_B) 
INNER JOIN Table_C AS C ON C.Numerical_Key_C = D.Link-To-C) 
INNER JOIN Table_A AS A ON A.Numerical_Key_A = D.Link-To-A
```

Note: i have no chance to test it. It's just an idea.

Finally i need to warn you: Access likes **()** /brackets/ while multiple joins are used.

**[EDIT2]**

Based on discussion, below query should return calculated field:

```
SELECT C.MetaLevel, R.LevelAdjustment, C.MetaLevel+ R.LevelAdjustment AS NominalLevel
FROM tblRank AS R INNER JOIN tblCreatures AS C ON R.ID = C.Rank;
```

If you would like to update *NominalLevel* in a *tblCreatures*, use query like this:

```
UPDATE tblCreatures AS C
INNER JOIN tblRank AS R ON R.ID = C.Rank
SET C.NominalLevel = (C.MetaLevel+ R.LevelAdjustment);
```

*NominalLevel* has been updated. You can select it also...

```
SELECT C.MetaLevel, R.LevelAdjustment, C.NominalLevel
FROM tblRank AS R INNER JOIN tblCreatures AS C ON R.ID = C.Rank;
```

Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: So, the query works, in that it produces a nice list of the three fields.  How do I use that in a Calculated Field, or otherwise to actually populate a new field in Table D with the results of a calculation using data in that query?

Comment: What field you want to calculate? Based on what criteria? To be able to answer, i need to know the logic you want to use.

Comment: In table D, there is a field, which I have labeled in the above snippit as "Link-to-C".  This field should be populated with the value of Link-to-A plus TableB.AdjustmentValue

Comment: No.  This doesn't work.  I'm reading up on Inner Joins now, and it seems like this is supposed to create a temporary relationship?  I already have a relationship built into the database, where Link-to-A = TableA.PrimaryKey and so forth, so I'm not sure what all the INNER JOINS are fore, and none of the commands here seem to do anything to actually populate my field D.Link-to-C as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RichardWinters, I do not see your database structure, so... Please post sample (dummy) data you want to join and post expected output, then i'll able to help you write proper query. OK?

Comment: Okay.  I'll start using the actual names in my database.  The purpose is to store creatures for a roleplaying game.  A creature has a "MetaLevel", which determines the rewards for defeating it.  A creature also has a "NominalLevel", which determines how strong its attacks are.  The NominalLevel is calculated based on its Rank, which also determines what types of attacks it gets.

Here are the exact fields in question:

Comment: `tblCreatures.MetaLevel (linked to tblMetaLevel.Level)
tblCreatures.Rank (linked to tblRank.ID)
tblCreatures.NominalLevel (linked to tblNominalLevel.Level)

tblRank.ID
tblRank.LevelAdjustment`

I need to automatically fill tblCreatures.NominalLevel with the formula "tblCreatures.MetaLevel + tblRank.LevelAdjustment".

Comment: Sample data:  `tblCreatures.MetaLevel = 20; tblCreatures.Rank = 1; tblCreature.NominalLevel = {CALCULATE THIS!}; tblRank.ID = 1; tblRank.LevelAdjustment = 5;`  The end result is that `tblCreature.NominalLevel` should equal 25.

Comment: Okay, this is strange.  The first query posted does indeed pull up all the calculated values I need.  However, the second query... doesn't do anything.  Well, it shows a column with "NominalLevel", but all the fields are empty and not updated.  The two queries use the same logic!  Why would one work and not the other?  And I really need the second to work...

Comment: I don't know. I tested it in my database and it works as well ;)

Comment: Looks like it was a type error.  Fixed, works now, thank you!